# Initialize static member array to zero

Tags: c++, arrays, static

Going by the document here http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf

> “Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage
>   duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other
>   initialization takes place”

If I have everything, i.e class declaration and main() in a single file (a must) I should be able to omit the initialization.
But, if I omit, I get "undefined reference" error during build.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo
{
    public:
        static int array[2];
};

int foo::array[2] = {0}; //I should be able to omit this line

int main()
{
    cout << "foo::array[0] = " << foo::array[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

PS: No C++11

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are misreading the standard. You can simply drop the `= {0}` part as the compiler will automatically initialize it with zeros.

You can *not* leave out the entire line because otherwise you just declare the array but you never define it anywhere - that's what is causing the problem for you.

Comment: For a 2D array which initialization is more correct? `int foo::array[2][2] = {{0}};` or `int foo::array[2][2] = {0};` or `int foo::array[2][2] = {};`

Comment: @ontherocks The first is invalid AFAICT, the latter two are equivalent, so the is no "more correct" version wrt to the last two.

Answer (score 0):

For a static data member of a class, one must compulsorily provide definition in the implementation file because,

static data has a single piece of storage regardless of how many objects are created, that storage must be defined in a single place. The compiler will not allocate storage for you. The linker will report an error if a static data member is declared but not defined.